# set column values equals to columnB minus columnA

Tags: mysql, sql

I want my MySql Column 'Time' to be update as Column 'End_Time' **Minus** Column 'Start_Time'

Note: End_Time & Start_Time are in DATETIME format....

Thanks

Comment: What is the datatype of column - Time?

Comment: datatype for Time column is Time only

Comment: So what will be the expected result if the output is more than 24 Hr or more than 30 days?

Comment: Output will always be within 24hrs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method,

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,Start_Time,End_Time)) --include sec
or
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,Start_Time,End_Time)*60) --diff in minute

eg

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,'2016-05-04 10:00:00','2016-05-04 11:29:00')*60)
```

Here `TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute` will return the diff in minutes and mutiple it *60 to get seconds, and use `SEC_TO_TIME` to convert from sec to Time.

Comment: is there any way to get exact difference...I mean if i subtract 04:05:34 from   09:00:00 I should get 04:54:26 rather than 04:54:00

Comment: answer modified , use the first query that include seconds also.

Answer (score 0):

Use Datediff function in mysql

[See here for DATEDIFF](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, '2015-06-01 13:13:55', '2015-06-03 10:15:20')

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, '2015-06-01 13:13:55', '2015-06-03 10:15:20')

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, '2015-06-01 13:13:55', '2015-06-03 10:15:20')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table 
set Time = (select 
            to_timestamp(End_Time,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp(Start_Time,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
            );
```